# Ejecutar metodo al seleccionar TextBox automático

Tags: c#

tengo una duda, lo que pasa es que tengo un método de operaciones, tomo los valores de dos textbox, sin embargo al seleccionar un tercer textbox, quiero que el método de operación se ejecute con solo seleccionar el textbox,puse el evento TextChanged pero no funciona que le dejo el método de operaciones, solo quiero saber en que acomodarlo o como activarlo al momento de seleccionar el TextBox5, LE DEJO EL MÉTODO DE OPERACIONES:

```
public void op()
{ 
         double qty = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox7.Text);
        double price = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text);
        double calcular = 0;
        calcular = (qty*price);
        TextBox5.Text = calcular.ToString();
}
```

Comment: ¿Winforms o Web Forms?

Comment: Perdón es en ambiente ASP.Net ,Web Forms :))

Comment: Si es asp.net, puedes usar el evento `onfocus()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando hay una propiedad por la cual no lanza el evento al lado del server.
Te cuento como le hice:

1 - Agregue los textbox y les puse la propiedad AutoPostBack = true

2 - Cree el evento TextChange para que llamara la función op()

Con eso funciona pero se refresca la pantalla cada momento, te anexo el codigo con mi ejemplo y también ese mismo comportamiento pero con jquery.

- Ejemplo con jquery

```js
function funcionOP() {
    var cantidad = parseFloat($("#txtCantidad").val());
    var precio = parseFloat($("#txtPrecio").val());

    cantidad = isNaN(cantidad) ? 0 : cantidad;
    precio = isNaN(precio) ? 0 : precio;

    $("#txtResultado").val(cantidad * precio);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h1>Desde code Behind C#</h1>
        qty<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        Price<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <h1>Con jquery</h1>
        qty<input type="number" id="txtCantidad" onchange="funcionOP();"/>
        <br />
        price<input type="number" id="txtPrecio" onchange="funcionOP();"/>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <br />
        <input type="number" id="txtResultado" readonly="true"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="WebForm1.js"></script>
</html>
```

- Codigo c# (Lado del server)

  ```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }

  public void op()
  {

      string valor1 = TextBox1.Text.Trim() == "" ? "0" : TextBox1.Text.Trim();
      string valor2 = TextBox2.Text.Trim() == "" ? "0" : TextBox2.Text.Trim();

      double v1;
      double v2;
      Double.TryParse(valor1, out v1);
      Double.TryParse(valor2, out v2);

      double qty = v1;
      double price = v2;
      double calcular = 0;
      calcular = (qty * price);
      TextBox3.Text = calcular.ToString();
  }


  protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      //Se llama la función cada vez que cambie el valor y se actualiza el resultado en el textbox3
      op();
  }

  protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      //Se llama la función cada vez que cambie el valor y se actualiza el resultado en el textbox3
      op();
  }
  ```

Espero que te sirva.  Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Me funcionó perfecto, casi no eh trabajado con JS, ahora veo que sera necesario aprender mas !! Saludos desde Tamaulipas.

Comment: Te recomiendo Jquery te facilita mucho la vida: https://www.codecademy.com/es/tracks/jquery-traduccion-al-espanol-america-latina-clone   puedes checar en esa liga y empezar, saludos desde Culiacán, Sinaloa :-)

Answer (score 0):

Debido a la naturaleza de las aplicacines web, este evento sucede en el lado del cliente y la forma mas habitual de controlarlo es a travez de Javascript mediante el evento onfocus, lo defines en tu control de la siguiente forma:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="textbox2" onfocus="SetTextInTextBox2()" />
```

Añades la funcion dentro de un tag  de la siguiente forma:

```
function SetTextInTextBox2()
{
    document.getElementById('textbox2').value = document.getElementById('textbox1').value;
}
```

**Editado**

Puedes crear la función op con Javascript y te daría la misma funcionalidad
porque lo que necesitas es modificar elementos de tipo texto, a travez de Javascript quedaría asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function op()
{ 
        var qty = parseFloat(document.getElementById('TextBox7').value);
        var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById('TextBox2').value);
        var calcular = 0;
        calcular = (qty*price);
        document.getElementById('TextBox5').value = calcular;
}
</script>
```

Para poder acceder a los elementos en el lado del cliente procura aplicarle la propiedad ID a tus asp:textbox de la siguiente forma:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox7"  />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox2"  />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox5" onfocus="op()" />
```

Comment: Ya que copias el código de [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526429/how-to-get-gotfocus-lostfocus-event-of-a-textbox-in-webforms-using-c-sharp), al menos modifícalo para que le sirva al OP para llamar a su método en el code behind :)

Comment: Gracias por comentar!!, pero en el código de C# no se podría hacer? y si no se puede, como llamo a mi método Op() a la función de javascript??

Comment: Se podría pero solo con el evento `OnTextChanged`  es decir hasta que salgas del control y no al darle clic. Si lo quieres usar con javascript, puedes ejecutar la función js desde c# con esto `RegisterStartupScript`

Comment: Segun el codigo que tienes, como solo deseas cambiar valores en cuadros de texto lo podrías hacer perfectamente desde el lado del cliente sin ir al servidor, olvida la funcion SetTextInTextBox2, modifiqué la respuesta para que tengas una mejor idea de como hacerlo.